# update View when model data changed(not database)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want test a solution  : capture image data from local camera , and display ！

This is my controller:

```
public class DevController : Controller
{
    public byte[] Pixels = null;
    Bitmap _bmp = new Bitmap(480, 272, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Graphics _g = null;       
    System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (_g == null)            
            _g = Graphics.FromImage(_bmp);

        _g.Clear(Color.Black);
        _g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 2, 2, 65, 31);
        _g.DrawString("hello ", new Font("Arial", 15f), Brushes.Yellow, new PointF(5f, 5f));

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        _bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

        Pixels = ms.ToArray();

        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        return View(this);
    }
}
```

use Timer to update model data:

```
void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_g == null)
    {
        _g = Graphics.FromImage(_bmp);
    }

    _g.Clear(Color.Black);
    _g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 2, 2, 65, 31);
    _g.DrawString(string.Format("hello :{0}", id++), new Font("Arial", 15f), Brushes.Yellow, new PointF(5f, 5f));

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    _bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);         
    Pixels = ms.ToArray();
}
```

View Code

```
<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Pixels)" id="u_image" />
```

The question is :
how can the View been changed automatically when the `Pixels` changed in the time?

Comment: what's happening here?  `return View(this);`

Comment: use controller object as Model， just for test

Comment: I've never seen a controller used that way, but I don't think this will work. The controller uses the view to generate html and send it to the browser. After that the controller is done. If you want to update things in the view you probably need to look at some asynchronous javascript to keep calling a controller method.